How to become a monk in Bangladesh?
I've read some texts on Buddhism and I want devote myself to it. I want to learn meditation.
How can I do that?

I think this is a tough situation. Islam is the official religion there and you are probably in a better position to gauge if minority religions enjoy equal treatment and respect when it comes to practising their faith. Have you consider neighbouring countries like India and esp. Myanmar where there is a significant Buddhist community?

The question in the title doesn't seem to be in line with the more general concern expressed in the main body. If you want general information on Buddhism and meditation you might want to highlight this in the title so as to attract broader interest, and clarifying the request in the main body.
